# problems using lucene of highlighter and completeness.

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search

Now I meet with a problem. 
Bellow is the content for index I wrote，

```
was written for a formula, it's written as this, indeed.[latxt]$$ \left( {a + b} \right)\left( {{1 \over a} + {1 \over b}} \right) \ge \left( {a \cdot {1 \over a} + b \cdot {1 \over b}} \right)^2  = 4 $$[/latxt] was written for a formula, it's written as this, indeed.
```

When I search for 1 \over b, using highlighter's SimpleFragmenter to control the length of the highlighter content. The result is just parts of the codes.

```
   {1 \over a} + b \cdot {<em>1 \over b</em>}} \right)^2
```

But what I really want is the whole content of the [latxt] marks, then compile it to a picture.

**The methods I am considering are below:**

- If there are [latxt] marks, do not use the highlighter, and just compile it to a picture, then according to the offset of term，get some periods. But this method is not accurate enough.
- To realize Fragmenter myself, wholly handle the the content where there are [latxt] marks, as I still can't master Fragmenter, maybe this method is not likely to choose.

So, I honestly hope you can show me some other ways which can be more convenient and easier to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use TermVectors with position and offsets. [This](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/05/26/accessing-words-around-a-positional-match-in-lucene/) post explains how.